# how to implement backend server authentication with google play games services for android

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

Maybe I overlooked something, but through Play Games Services documentation https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart,I did not yet get any idea about how to implement backend server authentication like how to get a token from Google's server and pass it to my own backend server to verify a login.  I wish someone can give me a clue. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: 
Create a button with standard google Login button

Step2 : Add a buttonclick  listener

Step 3 : In listner check for google play services availablity

```
public void googleLoginClicked(View v){
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            pickUserAccount();
        }else{
            showToast("Google Play Services is not installed or updated in your deivce", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
```

protected boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode =

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
             //   Log.i("GCM", "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Step 4:

search for google accounts in phone:

```
private void pickUserAccount() {
        String[] accountTypes = new String[]{"com.google"};
        Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
                accountTypes, false, null, null, null, null);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT);
    }
```

Step5:

onActivityResult:

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mEmail = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                getUsername(null);
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                showToast("You must pick an account",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }

        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extra = data.getExtras();
            String oneTimeToken = extra.getString("authtoken");
            getUsername(oneTimeToken);

        }

    }
```

Step6: ON success get username from google using a background task

AsyncTask:

```
doinbackground(){
...
fetchToken
...
}


 protected String fetchToken() throws IOException {
        try {
            return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableException) {
            // GooglePlayServices.apk is either old, disabled, or not present, which is
            // recoverable, so we need to show the user some UI through the activity.
            mActivity.handleException(userRecoverableException);
        } catch (GoogleAuthException fatalException) {
            onError("Unrecoverable error " + fatalException.getMessage(), fatalException);
        }
        return null;
    }
```